# Using Arcanimator in android app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

Hi i want to use [ArcAnimator](https://github.com/asyl/ArcAnimator) and [ArcLayout](https://github.com/ogaclejapan/ArcLayout) in one android project .
for that i using this dependencys

```
 compile 'com.ogaclejapan.arclayout:library:1.0.1@aar'
 compile 'com.github.asyl.animation:arcanimator:1.0.0'
```

but i give this error message

```
cannot resolve symbol'SupportAnimator'
cannot resolve symbol'ViewAnimationUtils'
```

in import line

```
import io.codetail.animation.SupportAnimator;
import io.codetail.animation.ViewAnimationUtils;
```

and its strange because i do not give this error in this lines

```
import io.codetail.animation.arcanimator.ArcAnimator;
import io.codetail.animation.arcanimator.Side;
```

which is in same library.
can anyone help me about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use other dependency to use Support Animator say https://github.com/kedzie/Support_v4_NineOldAndroids. Support Animator is not there in the package of the library that you have used. It’s not showing inside the package you have used, you can check at https://github.com/asyl/ArcAnimator/tree/master/animator/src/main/java/io/codetail/animation/arcanimator.

Also you can take help of some samples given here at https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal/releases.